# how to override onCreate method without calling super.onCreate

Tags: android

I am new in android .My question is how to override `onCreate` method without calling `super.onCreate()`. If I am doing so it give exception `SuperNotCalledException`.
There is any way to override `onCreate` method without calling `super.onCreate` !!
 Thanx

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You HAVE TO to call `super.onCreate()`. That's why there is an Exception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **nonsense**

Answer (score 6):

> My question is how to override onCreate method without calling super.onCreate()

That is not supported. Please call `super.onCreate()`, typically as the first line in your `onCreate()` implementation.